# How to fix binding issue in Vue js

Tags: vue.js, v-model

[image]

```
 <tr :key="indexProject"  v-for="(project,indexProject) in currentUserProjects">
           <td>
              <div>
                {{project.name}} -  {{project.client.name}}
              </div>
           </td>
           <td :key="indexDay"  v-for="(day,indexDay) in days">
              <v-text-field v-if="indexDay < 7 && daysMatrix.length > 0" v-model="daysMatrix[indexProject] 
                 [indexDay].hours" v-on:input="calculateProjectTotal(daysMatrix[indexProject][indexDay].hours, indexProject)"/>
              <div v-if="indexDay >= 7 && daysMatrix.length > 0 ">
                 {{daysMatrix[indexProject][indexDay]}}
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="remove_time">
               <v-btn @click="remove(indexProject)"  icon>
                   <v-icon>mdi-delete-forever</v-icon>
               </v-btn>
            </td>
         </tr>






remove(indexProject){
                console.log(indexProject)
                this.daysMatrix[indexProject][0].hours = 0
                this.daysMatrix[indexProject][1].hours = 0
                this.daysMatrix[indexProject][2].hours = 0
                this.daysMatrix[indexProject][3].hours = 0
                this.daysMatrix[indexProject][4].hours = 0
                this.daysMatrix[indexProject][5].hours = 0
                this.daysMatrix[indexProject][6].hours = 0
 },
```

As you see the screenshot and code, I tried to set all fields for time input when I clicked the remove button. but it happend nothing. Please help me. Thank you in advanced

this is the additional code 
[image]

Comment: Do you see the console logging? Are there any errors in the console? At first glance it seems likely to be a reactivity issue but it's difficult to be sure without knowing how the data is initially populated. Could you include the code that does that initial population of `daysMatrix`? Try using `$set` to set the value, which may fix it but even if it does the proper fix would be to ensure the data is reactive in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for your reply
Yes, I can see the correct value on the console.

Comment: Could you include the code that populates `daysMatrix`? The current code just shows the creation of an empty array. The critical stage is when values are added to that array. You have to do it just right or they won't end up reactive.

Comment: I am using Vuex. other functions work well, very weird.
How can I share the code with you?

Comment: Just put it in the question. Also, please post all code as text, not as pictures. Chances are the initial population is falling foul of one of the reactivity caveats. If you want to check yourself take a look at https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Comment: $set is a great idea
It works
but I have one concern
daysMatrix[indexProject][days].hour
how can I process days array?

Comment: I don't know what that means. As I mentioned previously, using `$set` may make the problem go away but it isn't really the correct fix. It's treating a symptom rather than addressing the underlying cause. The real problem here is that you're populating `daysMatrix` in a non-reactive way but I can't help you with that unless you share the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209671/discussion-between-liqiang-and-skirtle).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, it's a reactivity issue. Only setting the whole value, using certain array methods, or using the .$set method will trigger the reactivity. You need to do something more like

```
const days = this.daysMatrix
days[indexProject][0].hours = 0
days[indexProject][1].hours = 0
//...

this.daysMatrix = days
```

or

```
this.daysMatrix[indexProject].forEach((value, index) => {
  this.$set(this.daysMatrix[indexProject][index], 'hours', 0)
})
```